# Getting `newsubscriptionvideos` from YouTube API returns 403 Forbidden

Tags: youtube-api

For couple of months I have used use this link to retrieve new video-links from YouTube 
every 20 mins, 24/7:

```
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/$MYUSERNAME/newsubscriptionvideos?max-results=50&v=2
```

Today suddenly, YouTube's API returned:

```
<errors xmlns='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005'>
    <error>
        <domain>GData</domain>
        <code>ServiceForbiddenException</code>
        <internalReason>Forbidden</internalReason>
    </error>
</errors>
```

I haven't change anything in my previously-working code. Has the API changed? How can I get new subscription videos?

I don't keep my subscriptions private at http://www.youtube.com/account_privacy

**This is no longer an issue, Google returned all to a previously working state.**

Comment: There is also an issue if you access API with token, `newsubscriptionvideos` returns inconsistent results and is limited to 50, see [this report](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=5215).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a transient bug in the YouTube API.